# two values in a excel cell

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, cell

I have a cell in excel with a range value: a-b, example: '23.5-34.7'

I want compute in another cell the following math: b-a (34.7-23.5), which would be the code in excel to do that? If the 2 values belong to the same cell how can I define them as a 2 different values in excel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the value "23.5-34.7" is stored inside cell A1 you can get

- 23.5 with the formula `=MID(A1,1,FIND("-",A1,1)-1)`
- 34.7 wth the formula `=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+1,999)`

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this using MID, LEN, RIGHT, LEFT, FIND functions generally. In your case the two numbers are separated by "-" so find the position of this and then take the string after that as `b`, and the string before as `a` and then do `b-a`.

For example if value 23.5-34.7 was in E20 then

```
=RIGHT(E20,LEN(E20)-FIND("-",E20,1))-LEFT(E20,FIND("-",E20,1)-1)
```

`LEFT(E20,FIND("-",E20,1)-1)` gives you 23.5

`RIGHT(E20,LEN(E20)-FIND("-",E20,1))` gives you 34.7

`=RIGHT(E20,LEN(E20)-FIND("-",E20,1))-LEFT(E20,FIND("-",E20,1)-1)` gives you 11.2

You can use combine with TRIM and SUBSTITUTE functions to get rid of white space at the start and end (TRIM) of strings, and within a string (SUBSTITUTE).

Answer (score 0):

QHarr is correct, but you need to add **"-"** so ...

=RIGHT(E20,LEN(E20)-FIND("-",E20,1)) **& "-" &** LEFT(E20,FIND("-",E20,1)-1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,

```
=REPLACE(E20, 1, FIND("-", E20), "")-REPLACE(E20, FIND("-", E20), LEN(E20), "")
```